# sqoop to mysql importing issue

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

I am using the following command to fetch data from mysql table to a hive table:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx/orderdbms \
--username=orderuser \
--password=orderpass \
--table=order \
--where="DATE(created)='2015-08-20'" \
--hive-import \
--hive-table=orderstat.order \
--target-dir=/user/ordermanager/sqoopdata/orders \
--direct
```

I am getting the following error while doing the above:

> Error reading from database: java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result
>   set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@1f16ebd3 is still active. No
>   statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and
>   in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on
>   any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
>   java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set
>   com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@1f16ebd3 is still active. No statements
>   may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a
>   given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active
>   streaming result sets before attempting more queries.     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:914)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkForOutstandingStreamingData(MysqlIO.java:2181)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1542)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3206)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:1232)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.getMaxBytesPerChar(Connection.java:3673)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Field.getMaxBytesPerCharacter(Field.java:482)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData.getPrecision(ResultSetMetaData.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:286)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:227)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:295)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1833)
>     at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
>     at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
>     at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)    at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)   at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)    at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)    at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236) 15/08/24 11:54:46 ERROR
>   tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job:
>   java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter   at
>   org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1651)  at
>   org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
>     at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
>     at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)    at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)   at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)    at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)    at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)

Can anyone please explain what is causing this? Is there a problem with the syntax or some connectivity issues between client & mysql server.

Comment: I am not aware of `hive` and `sqoop`. Reading error stack message, I think `sqoop` import is not completed before you issued a `hive` import and hence you may require to close a connection and start 2nd import explicit.

Comment: can you try changing  mysql jar into latest version jar in the sqoop lib directory

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the option

```
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```